# Blocks in NSSortDescriptors - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, nssortdescriptor

I have a `switch` statement which creates a relevant `NSSortDescriptor`. For some of the `NSSortDescriptors` I am using a `block` as a custom `comparator` (to compare `CMTimes`). The following code works fine but I would like to add some more `NSSortDescriptors` also comparing `CMTimes`. As the `block` is always the same is it possible to create a `variable` to hold the `block` so I don't need to keep copying and pasting messy code.  I guess it should be possible but I can't seem to get it to work.  I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you!

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor; 

switch (mode) {
    case 1:
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"startTime" ascending: YES comparator:^(id first, id second){
                    CMTime time1 = [first CMTimeValue];
                    CMTime time2 = [second CMTimeValue];
                    if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, <, time2)) 
                        return NSOrderedAscending;
                    else if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, >, time2))
                        return NSOrderedDescending;
                    else
                        return NSOrderedSame;
        }];
        break;
    case 2:
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"startTime" ascending: NO comparator:^(id first, id second){
                    CMTime time1 = [first CMTimeValue];
                    CMTime time2 = [second CMTimeValue];
                    if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, <, time2)) 
                        return NSOrderedAscending;
                    else if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, >, time2))
                        return NSOrderedDescending;
                    else
                        return NSOrderedSame;
        }];
        break;
    case 3:
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"info" ascending: YES];
        break;
    case 4:       
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"info" ascending: NO];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a block variable so that you don't have to copy and paste the block code.

```
NSComparator comparisonBlock = ^(id first,id second) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
};
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"startTime" ascending: YES comparator:comparisonBlock];
```

Comment: Thanks DHamrick.  That works perfectly.  I think I understand blocks a bit better now...

Answer (score 4):

You could do something along the lines of

```
NSComparator myBlock = ^(id first, id second) {
    CMTime time1 = [first CMTimeValue];
    CMTime time2 = [second CMTimeValue];
    if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, <, time2)) 
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(time1, >, time2))
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

This will create you a variable myBlock that is a block with return type NSComparator, and take two id type arguments.

You should then be able to call for example:

```
sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"startTime" ascending: YES comparator:myBlock];
```

And everything should work nicely.

Hope this helps, let me know if there's anything else I can help with :)

Comment: Hi George.  For some reason I can't get your solution to work... in particular... `(^myBlock)(id, id)` .   If I just replace that with `myBlock` as in DHamrick's answer above it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, that was completely my fault. You're absolutely right I typed that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use `@property (nonatomic, copy)` for property (don't forget to release), or just define a block before your assignments.